# Comparing Object Fields to a couple million rows with a SearchCursor from arcpy

Tags: arcpy, sql-server, cursor, python-2.7, performance

I'm new to GIS.

I'm using arcpy.da.SearchCursor to read from a SQL server, and when I read through the first table I create objects ~350,000 of them.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(SktSegmentTable, SktSegmentData, "status = 'A'and lrsn = '754'")
for row in cursor:
    count  += 1
    if(count % 100000 == 0):
        print("Processed %d rows" %count)

    sketchList.append(UnionSketchData(
        row[SktSegmentData.index("lrsn")],
        row[SktSegmentData.index("extension")], 
        row[SktSegmentData.index("status")], 
        row[SktSegmentData.index("segment_id")],
        row[SktSegmentData.index("vector_start")] )
        )
del cursor
```

This is working fine and the real problem comes in when I have to read from another table that has around 2.5 million rows.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(SktVectorTable, SktVectorData, "status = 'A'") #and lrsn = '97429'")
print("Going into VECTOR TABLE")
countRow = 0
count = 0
for row in cursor:
    count  += 1
    if(count % 10000 == 0):
        print("Processed %d rows" %count)
    if(count % 100000 == 0):
        print("Processed %d rows" %count)
    seqCount = 0
# Do a check for every sketchList obj
    for item in sketchList:
    # Check if lrsn is equal to row's lrsn
        if(row[SktVectorData.index("lrsn")] == item.lrsn):
            # If we have a match on lrsn, then check if the items segment_id is the same
            if(row[SktVectorData.index("segment_id")] == item.segment_id ):
                if(row[SktVectorData.index("extension")] == item.extension ):
                #if The segment_id is the same for the item, append the vector string into seq_numbers
                sketchList[seqCount].seq_numbers.append(row[SktVectorData.index("vector")])
        seqCount += 1
del cursor
```

This runs incredibly slow and will take around 120 hours on my machine.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this run quickly?

I've been trying to put the 2.5 million entries into a dict but haven't been able to successfully get that to work.

Comment: Considering what you're doing I'm not surprised it's slow, you might want to put in a **break** if the item is found to escape out of the **for item in sketchList** loop, as you have it the loop will continue *even after the item is found*, that should speed it up a little.

Comment: What UnionSketchData does?

Comment: I think you  should look into sets, they are much faster than lists. Why didnt the dictionary work?

Answer (score 1):

I will not guarantee that this will be faster, because I have not tested it, but I think it will be.

Try copying your SQL Server layer out into a file geodatabase feature class on your C: drive, and then run your code against that instead.

Test smaller rather than larger SQL Server layers first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing each entry in the 2,5 million row table with each list element in the 350k list you are doing 2500000*350000 = 875 billion comparisons which should take some time.

You can use sets to check which entries match and only store matches in the dictionary.

Example:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'X:\database.gdb'
data = 'Big_table'
subdata = 'Smaller_table'
fields = ['checkfield1','checkfield2','checkfield3','valuefield']

sublist = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(subdata,fields[:-1])]
datalist = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(data,fields)]

subset = set(sublist)
dataset = set([v[:-1] for v in datalist])
matches = subset.intersection(dataset)

d = {i[0]:i[-1] for i in datalist if i[:-1] in matches}

sublist = [list(i)+[d[i[0]]] if i in matches else list(i) for i in sublist]
```